# NoMethod Error. Regarding Mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test if a mailer is working correctly via a mailer test but when I try to load the view I get the following error:

```
undefined method ` ' for #<DailyMailerPreview:0x007fb2bd79af78>
```

Here is the mailer preview code:

```
class DailyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
 def new_jobs 
  @jobs = Job.where("created_at > ?", 1.day.ago)

  return if @jobs.empty?

  User.find_each do |user|
   mail to: user.email, subject: 'New Jobs'
  end
  end
  end
```

The issue is that I don't understand where the NoMethod error is coming from. I'm pretty sure it's a silly typo but I can't seem to understand where the typo is at.

Thank you big time ahead of time.

Edit:

Stack trace:

[image]

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that exception?

Comment: Yes, but it's a little long

Comment: I believe I added it.

Comment: So you're getting a NoMethodError complaining about a method called `' '` (a single space) at `return if @jobs.empty?`? Do you have some funky unicode in there?